# GWT CellTable sorting

Tags: gwt

I am using celltable of GWT. And I am trying to sort a data of a column according to name of the user. But anyhow it is not getting sorted. I am following the below link.

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504634/set-default-sort-order-for-initial-header-click-on-gwt-cell-table

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to define your own ColumnSortEvent handler.

See the docs on [column sorting](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable#columnSorting) for more information